# Getting variable from function inside of class into a separate class function in python

Tags: python, function, class, variables, computer-vision

I have two python files that contain 2 classes. I want to get a variable that is within one function within one class into a function in a different class.

Specifically, the class `CaptureFrames` creates a variable called `frames_count`, which keeps track of the current frame of the video being processed. The class `ProcessMasks` does processing on a frame and returns a variable `hr_fft`. When this variable is returned, I want to create a tuple containing the `hr_fft` and the `frames_count` variable together, so I can keep track of what specific frame is associated with the `hr_fft` variable.

I've tried labeling it as `CaptureFrames.frames_count` and `CaptureFrames.capture_frames.frames_count` but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

The classes look like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from models import LinkNet34
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import time
import sys

class CaptureFrames():

    def __init__(self, bs, source, show_mask=False):
        self.frame_counter = 0
        self.batch_size = bs
        self.stop = False
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.model = LinkNet34()
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load('linknet.pth', map_location='cpu'))
        self.model.eval()
        self.model.to(self.device)
        self.show_mask = show_mask
        
    def __call__(self, pipe, source):
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.capture_frames(source)
  
    def capture_frames(self, source):
        
        img_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((256,256)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])
    
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.model.eval()
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
        time_1 = time.time()

        #######################################################

        self.frames_count = 0

        #######################################################

        while grabbed:
            
            (grabbed, orig) = camera.read()
            if not grabbed:
                continue
            
            shape = orig.shape[0:2]
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame,(256,256), cv2.INTER_LINEAR )
            
            
            k = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k != -1:
                self.terminate(camera)
                break

            a = img_transform(Image.fromarray(frame))
            a = a.unsqueeze(0)
            imgs = Variable(a.to(dtype=torch.float, device=self.device))
            pred = self.model(imgs)
            
            pred= torch.nn.functional.interpolate(pred, size=[shape[0], shape[1]])
            mask = pred.data.cpu().numpy()
            mask = mask.squeeze()
            
            # im = Image.fromarray(mask)
            # im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3))
            # im3 = im2.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(5))
            # mask = np.array(im3)
            
            mask = mask > 0.8
            orig[mask==0]=0
            self.pipe.send([orig])

            if self.show_mask:
                cv2.imshow('mask', orig)
            
            if self.frames_count % 30 == 29:
                time_2 = time.time()
                sys.stdout.write(f'\rFPS: {30/(time_2-time_1)}')
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time_1 = time.time()

        #######################################################

            self.frames_count+=1

        #######################################################

        self.terminate(camera)

    
    def terminate(self, camera):
        self.pipe.send(None)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        camera.release()
```

and

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pulse import Pulse
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread
from plot_cont import DynamicPlot
from capture_frames import CaptureFrames
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from utils import *
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys


class ProcessMasks():

    def __init__(self, sz=270, fs=30, bs=30, size=256):
        print('init')
        self.stop = False
        self.masked_batches = []
        self.batch_mean = []
        self.signal_size = sz
        self.batch_size = bs
        self.signal = np.zeros((sz, 3))
        self.pulse = Pulse(fs, sz, bs, size)
        self.hrs = []
        self.save_results = True

    def __call__(self, pipe, plot_pipe, source):
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.plot_pipe = plot_pipe
        self.source = source
        compute_mean_thread =  Thread(target=self.compute_mean)
        compute_mean_thread.start()
        
        extract_signal_thread =  Thread(target=self.extract_signal)
        extract_signal_thread.start()

        self.rec_frames()
        
        compute_mean_thread.join()
        extract_signal_thread.join()
  
    def rec_frames(self):
        while True and not self.stop:
            data = self.pipe.recv()

            if data is None:
                self.terminate()
                break
            batch = data[0]

            self.masked_batches.append(batch)
    
    def process_signal(self, batch_mean):
        size = self.signal.shape[0]
        b_size = batch_mean.shape[0]

        self.signal[0:size-b_size] = self.signal[b_size:size]
        self.signal[size-b_size:] = batch_mean
        p = self.pulse.get_pulse(self.signal)
        p = moving_avg(p, 6)
        hr = self.pulse.get_rfft_hr(p)
        if len(self.hrs) > 300: self.hrs.pop(0)

        self.hrs.append(hr)
        if self.plot_pipe is not None and self.stop:
            self.plot_pipe.send(None)
        elif self.plot_pipe is not None:
            self.plot_pipe.send([p, self.hrs])
        else:

        #######################################################
        # I want to insert frames_count here, so when I print 
        # hr_fft, I can also print the frame_count for that 
        # observation.

        #######################################################

            hr_fft = moving_avg(self.hrs, 3)[-1] if len(self.hrs) > 5 else self.hrs[-1]
            print(hr_fft, CaptureFrames.frames_count)
            sys.stdout.write(f'\rHr: {round(hr_fft, 0)}')
            sys.stdout.flush()
    
    def extract_signal(self):
        signal_extracted = 0
        
        while True and not self.stop:
            if len(self.batch_mean) == 0:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                continue
            
            mean_dict = self.batch_mean.pop(0)
            mean = mean_dict['mean']

            if mean_dict['face_detected'] == False:
                if self.plot_pipe is not None:
                    self.plot_pipe.send('no face detected')
                continue
            if signal_extracted >= self.signal_size:
                self.process_signal(mean)
            else:
                self.signal[signal_extracted: signal_extracted + mean.shape[0]] = mean
            signal_extracted+=mean.shape[0]
    

    def compute_mean(self):
        curr_batch_size = 0
        batch = None
        while True and not self.stop:                
            if len(self.masked_batches) == 0:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                continue
            
            mask = self.masked_batches.pop(0)     
            if batch is None:
                batch = np.zeros((self.batch_size, mask.shape[0], mask.shape[1], mask.shape[2]))
            
            if curr_batch_size < (self.batch_size - 1):
                batch[curr_batch_size] = mask
                curr_batch_size+=1
                continue
            
            batch[curr_batch_size] = mask
            curr_batch_size = 0

            non_zero_pixels = (batch!=0).sum(axis=(1,2))
            total_pixels = batch.shape[1] * batch.shape[2]
            avg_skin_pixels = non_zero_pixels.mean()
            m = {'face_detected': True, 'mean': np.zeros((self.batch_size, 3))}
            if (avg_skin_pixels + 1) / (total_pixels) < 0.05:
                m['face_detected'] = False
            else:
                m['mean'] = np.true_divide(batch.sum(axis=(1,2)), non_zero_pixels+1e-6)

            self.batch_mean.append(m)

    def terminate(self):
        
        if self.plot_pipe is not None:
            self.plot_pipe.send(None)
        self.savePlot(self.source)
        self.saveresults()
        self.stop = True
    
    def saveresults(self):
        """
        saves numpy array of heart rates as hrs
        saves numpy array of power spectrum as fft_spec
        """
        np.save('hrs', np.array(self.hrs))
        np.save('fft_spec', np.array(self.pulse.fft_spec))
```

For reference, they are called together an run with this file:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pulse import Pulse
import time
from threading import Lock, Thread
from plot_cont import DynamicPlot
from capture_frames import CaptureFrames
from process_mask import ProcessMasks

from utils import *
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser

class RunPOS():
    def __init__(self,  sz=270, fs=28, bs=30, plot=False):
        self.batch_size = bs
        self.frame_rate = fs
        self.signal_size = sz
        self.plot = plot

    def __call__(self, source):
        time1=time.time()
        
        mask_process_pipe, chil_process_pipe = mp.Pipe()
        self.plot_pipe = None
        if self.plot:
            self.plot_pipe, plotter_pipe = mp.Pipe()
            self.plotter = DynamicPlot(self.signal_size, self.batch_size)
            self.plot_process = mp.Process(target=self.plotter, args=(plotter_pipe,), daemon=True)
            self.plot_process.start()
        
        process_mask = ProcessMasks(self.signal_size, self.frame_rate, self.batch_size)

        mask_processer = mp.Process(target=process_mask, args=(chil_process_pipe, self.plot_pipe, source, ), daemon=True)
        mask_processer.start()
        
        capture = CaptureFrames(self.batch_size, source, show_mask=True)
        capture(mask_process_pipe, source)

        mask_processer.join()
        if self.plot:
            self.plot_process.join()
        time2=time.time()
        time2=time.time()
        print(f'time {time2-time1}')

def get_args():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-s', '--source', dest='source', default=0,
                        help='Signal Source: 0 for webcam or file path')
    parser.add_option('-b', '--batch-size', dest='batchsize', default=30,
                        type='int', help='batch size')
    parser.add_option('-f', '--frame-rate', dest='framerate', default=25,
                        help='Frame Rate')

    (options, _) = parser.parse_args()
    return options
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    args = get_args()
    source = args.source
    runPOS = RunPOS(270, args.framerate, args.batchsize, True)
    runPOS(source)
```

Comment: maybe a word of advice - if you have a complicated code but you want to achieve some simple effects, build a toy model (2 very simple classes with 1 variable and one function each only) and try to implement your solution there - you will learn a lot and have a better chance to actually understand what is going on

Comment: +1 for that.  I think there's a much easier way to do what you're trying to do, but there's way too much code here for me to simply rewrite it to demonstrate.  If you can come up with a minimum example it'll be a lot easier to explain/understand and then you can apply that understanding to the larger body of code.

Comment: Thanks, that is good advice.